# Can't access to a private method in Dart Library

Tags: dart, syntax-error, private

I have to access to a private method in a Class. I created a library with inside the Class, imported it but it can't still recognize. I have the same problem also with private variables.

Example:

file **buffer.dart**:

```
    library buflib;

    class Buffer{

            void _record(){
                    [...]
            }

    }
```

in the same folder: **engine.dart**

```
    import 'buffer.dart';

    class Engine {

            Buffer _buff = Buffer()

            [...]
            void myMethod(){
                    [...]
                    this._buff._record();
            }
    }
```

I have this error:

> The method '_record' isn't defined for the type 'Buffer'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining >a method named '_record'.dartundefined_method

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, each separate `.dart` file is a separate library.  Since private identifiers are private to the library, they won't be visible to other `.dart` files.

You can use the `library` and `part of` directives to group multiple `.dart` files into the same library, but [those directives aren't documented](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/1263).

Answer (score 0):

u cant call private methods or variables from out there classes .... u should change it to public by removing "under score"

Comment: From dart [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility) I found this: "_The import and library directives can help you create a modular and shareable code base. Libraries not only provide APIs, but are a unit of privacy: identifiers that start with an underscore are visible only inside the library. Every Dart app is a library, even if it doesn’t use a library directive._". I could be inside the libriry so I should see them